# Mysql datatype if expected number of characters in a column is around 150K

Tags: mysql, types, data-modeling

I read that in MySql varchar allows a (variable) max size of 65KB. Text data type  fixed max size is 65K. Meaning if a column is declared of type Text and field has only one character, it will still take up disk space of 65KB and similarly when loaded into memory takes up 65KB. Is this correct?

Also is this the same for medium text (occupying 16MB even if that column has just one character)?

Lets say i need to declare a column which will be occupied by strings with number of characters in the range of 150K, i cannot use text and can use medium text but wondering if i will be wasting lot of disk space/memory. What is a better way to do this. One way i can think of is to create 3 rows (split 150k characters into 3 rows of 50K), but is there is a better way of doing this

Comment: See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings

Comment: If English is not your first language, and the MySQL docs do not have a version in a language you are fluent in, what Paul's link basically says is only CHAR and BINARY take their full space; all the rest only use as much as needed for the current data in the field (plus a little more to remember how much data is in the field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, variable length data types like VARCHAR and TEXT and their cousins do not occupy as much space as their maximum size. They only occupy the length of the string they store, and this can vary row by row, as you store strings of different lengths.

They also have between 1 and 4 bytes per row to encode the length. For example, a VARCHAR(255) is stored with 1 preceding byte, because 1 byte can encode any length up to 255. Whereas LONGTEXT requires 4 bytes to encode the length, because that's what is required for the 4GB maximum length of a LONGTEXT. Following the bytes encoding the length, the actual data content only needs to be as long as the respective string.

It's a bit more complicated than that, since InnoDB stores all data in pages of uniform size (16KB by default), so long strings must be split over multiple pages.

For a column where you expect typical data will be 150K characters, you should use MEDIUMTEXT. The VARCHAR and TEXT types can't store 150K characters.

The variable-length quality does not apply to the CHAR type, which always stores the full length according to the definition of the column. I use CHAR only for strings that are of fixed size on every row, so there's no wasted space.